# How can I use a formula so every second row is empty?

Tags: excel

I have two sheets inside Excel like this:

```
*Sheet 1*
| 20 |   |   |
|----|---|---|
| 21 |   |   |
| 22 |   |   |
| 23 |   |   |
```

```
*Sheet 2*
| Referenz |   |
|----------|---|
| 21       |   |
|          |   |
| 22       |   |
|          |   |
| 23       |   |
```

I would like the output in sheet 2 as shown. Now I tried leaving space between the cells by dragging it down, but it doesn't work as expected. I also had a look at *INDEX* but it is not what I'm looking for.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Check [this article](https://excel.tips.net/T005405_Skipping_Rows_when_Filling.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in cells `A2:A4` on the first sheet and you want the output on second sheet starting from second row, you can try following formula in sheet 2 row 2:

`=IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,CEILING(ROW()/2,1)),"")`

Edit:

If I have understood what you need correctly then you can use a formula like

`=Sheet1!A2&CHAR(10)`

Copy down...!

Comment: I'm sorry this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: @Kektuto - maybe explain what exactly you are looking for then? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I found a solution, I wrote a PHP script which gives me the number and an ENTER

Comment: @Kektuto see the edit and the other formula. Maybe this is what you were looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

=IF(ISEVEN(ROW());A2+1;"")

Should give you the following result:

[image]

In case you want the rows that are uneven, just switch the "value_if_true" and "value_if_false" of the IF() formula.